# Плохо работает многопоточность

Tags: python, многопоточность, telegram-bot

Всех приветствую. Я сделал скрипт, который должен отправлять ежесекундно отправлять данные в телеграмм бот. Использую телеграмм API, отправка через библиотеку `httpx` и для каждого пользователя я выделял отдельный поток. Я для теста вбил в базу данных 10000 пользователей, запустив свой скрипт, производительность упала очень сильно. Раньше когда я запускал одного пользователя, то сообщения от телеграмм бота приходили ежесекундно, но при 10000 пользователях, приходят раз в 5 минут. Прошу помогите, решить не легкую задачку для меня, может вы можете посоветовать какую либо другую альтернативу для решение проблемы

Код:

```
from read_sql_config import read_db_config
import config
import asyncio
from threading import *
import httpx
import mysql.connector


# Инициализация Базы данных
db_config = read_db_config()
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)

Data_base = [] # Список данных с БД

def requests_message(id_telegram, wallet):
    while True:
        # Получение данных с сервера с помощью API
        try:
            response = httpx.get('https://apilist.tronscan.org/api/transaction',
                params={
                    'address': wallet,
                    'limit': 3,
                    'sort': '-timestamp',
                })   
            print(id_telegram)
            # Отбор нужных данных полученных с сервера
            in_address = response.json()['data'][0]['ownerAddress']
            to_address = response.json()['data'][0]['toAddress']
            token = response.json()['data'][0]['tokenInfo']['tokenName'].upper()
            # Отправление данных с помощью телеграм API
            httpx.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{config.api_token}/sendMessage?',
                        params={
                            'chat_id': id_telegram,
                            'text': (f"Полученные данные с кошелька {wallet}\n{in_address, to_address, token}")
                        })
        except:
            pass

class AsyncIterator:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.iter = iter(seq)

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            return next(self.iter)
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopAsyncIteration

# Загрузка базы данных в список
async def iter_row():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(300)
        if not rows:
            break
        async for row in AsyncIterator(rows):
            Data_base.append(row)  

# Запуск на получение и отправку данных
async def brute_force():
    async for row in AsyncIterator(Data_base): 
        Thread(target=requests_message, args=(row[1], row[2])).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(iter_row())
    loop.run_until_complete(brute_force())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Тут скорее всего дело не в многопоточности, читали вот это? https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#broadcasting-to-users Телеграм просит не спамить запросами чаще, чем 30 штук в секунду, а 10 000 пользователей поделить на 30 - как раз 5 минут выходит задержки

Comment: @mrEvgenX спасибо большое, а все понять не мог, в чем же проблема в следующий раз буду лучше читать документацию